# Can't access methods of postgis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

I try to build my rails env with postgis. The following is the extension of my db:

```
                                        List of installed extensions
       Name       | Version |   Schema   |                             Description                             
------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------

 plpgsql          | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language

 postgis          | 2.1.3   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions

 postgis_topology | 2.1.3   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
(3 rows)
```

And I also can see the " t.spatial  "location",   limit: {:srid=>0, :type=>"geometry"}" in my schema.rb after add column and migration the database.

While in the console and rb file, I can't access the postgis method like:

```
> e.location = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(121.04238 24.777656)', 4326)
NoMethodError: undefined method `ST_GeomFromText' for main:Object
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
```

Or in ruby file:

```
@data.location = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' + params[:longitude] +' ' + params[:latitude] + ')', 4326)
```

get the server error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `ST_GeomFromText' for #<DataController:0x000000053ee388>):
```

I try some idea from internet, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostGIS' methods are supposed to be used in SQLs, rather than Ruby code. See [examples in the official document](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html)